# Latex - Tabu Package - Missing Number and illegal unit of measure

Tags: latex

I've run into a few Latex Errors, while using a Latex Model for a job application. I used it once before and there it worked. But now I get some Errors of the "tabu package". I searched a long time now for a fix, but could not find anything.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.H0 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.H0 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.H0 
l.129 }

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.H0 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.H0 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \xdef 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \xdef 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.D0 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.D0 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.D0 
l.129 }

I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.D0 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \tabu@0.D0 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \xdef 
l.129 }

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \xdef 
l.129 }

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

My Code from this section looks like this. Does anyone know, what is wrong with my code?

```
\section{IT--Kenntnisse}
\eintragKb{}{\begin{tabu} to \maincolumnwidth {p{\tabBreite}@{\hspace{\tabSpace}}X{l}}
    {\mdseries xxx}: & xxx, xxx\\
    {\mdseries xxx}: & xxx, xxx\\
    {\mdseries xxx}: & xxx, xxx, xxx\\ 
    {\mdseries xxx}: & xxx, xxx, xxx\\
    %{\mdseries ...}: & ...
\end{tabu}
}
```

Comment: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf Isn't the syntax `\begin{tabu}{ ... }`?

Comment: Thanks for the Comment. I checked the Syntax, but it is definitly correct. I just found that the updated moderncv package is causing the problem. Since it does not work with tabu anymore.

Comment: When I provide values for the missing lengths and a dummy def. for `\eintragKb` I get no error.  Please provide the a small compilable document demonstrating the problem.